# Docker: Is running tests of a windows product on linux container good?

Tags: file, docker, web, host

I have a ASP.NET website which I develop on a windows machine and the users of the website are also 100% windows users.
My question is, if I want to user docker to test the application (with selenium for instance) is using a Linux container a good thing? 
Wouldn't that be a misrepresentation of what the production environment?
I just started using docker, and what I though of ideally was - 
 
- I will merge my code to the main branch and deploy in to some VM (Call it VM1).
- On another VM a docker container which has his host file point to VM1, and using that container it will what's in VM1.

Can't someone please focus me on the right path? :)

Thanks, Alex.